# Split lines from textbox to 2 other textboxes if it contains a specific word

Tags: vb.net

Hello im trying to split data from a textbox to 2 different textboxes,

But with this method the apples will also be added to the pear basket,

What am i doing wrong?

(fruitbasket.lines.tolist contains both the words "apples" and pears")

```
Dim split As New List(Of String)
        split = fruitbasket.Lines.ToList
        For i As Integer = split.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If split(i).Contains("apples") And apples.Text = "" Then
                applesbasket.Text = applesbasket.Text + split(i).ToString.Trim


            ElseIf applesbasket.Text <> "" Then
                applesbasket.Text = applesbasket.Text & System.Environment.NewLine + split(i).ToString.Trim

            End If


            If split(i).Contains("pears") And pearsbasket.Text = "" Then
                pearsbasket.Text = pearsbasket.Text + split(i).ToString.Trim

            ElseIf pearsbasket.Text <> "" Then
                pearsbasket.Text = pearsbasket.Text & System.Environment.NewLine + split(i).ToString.Trim
            End If

        Next
```

Comment: Pay attention to the conditions of both `ElseIf`s.  Can you see why the conditions are wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just nudge you in the right direction.

Both your `if` statements include a condition to make sure you only get apples where you only want apples, and pears where you only want pears. (e.g.: `If split(i).Contains("apples")...`)

But both your `ElseIf` statements do not restrict by fruit type.  Can you see how that would cause your problem?

I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, its working now thank you very much